# Subversion svn:mergeinfo record in the trunk about itself

Tags: svn, merge, mergeinfo

I'm looking into a problem we have with a merge and I found something in the recent past that I hope somebody could tell me wether it is a sign of problem or not.

I found in the `svn:mergeinfo` on the `^/trunk` itself the following record:

```
/trunk:1234
```

Is there a normal scenario where it is logical to have a merge info record in the trunk containing info about the trunk itself or is this the result of something that went wrong?

In case it's relevant: we didn't do renaming of the trunk. The "trunk record" in `svn:mergeinfo` seems to be added during a reintegrate merge of a feature branch

**Edit:**
It seems the `/trunk:1234` mergeinfo record was unexpectedly added to the trunk together with the expected `/branches/somebranch:1235-1241` when `/branches/somebranch` was reintegrated. It was the first time Subversion 1.8 was used hence it used the now automatic reintegration feature. Also the 1234 number is not random, it is the version the repository had right before the branch was was created.

We didn't find anything we could have done wrong. We concluded that it may have been a bug in the Subversion client (TortoiseSVN-1.8.4.24972-x64-svn-1.8.5)